# Blockcypher Websocket endpoint not working

Tags: websocket, blockcypher

I am using the Blockcypher API for test bitcoin transactions and I have troubles with the websocket API endpoint.
When sending the regular ping object after creating a new Websocket it works fine:

```
this.ws.onopen = () => {
  this.ws.send(JSON.stringify({"event": "ping"}))
```

but when trying to check the confidence of a transaction like this we get an error

`this.ws.onopen = () => {
      this.ws.send(JSON.stringify({event: 'tx-confidence', address:'<bitcoin address as string>', confidence:0.9}))`

Is there anything wrong with the datatypes? Any help would be great!

[API reference](https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/bitcoin/?javascript#types-of-events)
[Event reference](https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/bitcoin/?javascript#oaptx)

Comment: were you able to solve the issue?

Comment: Hi Ronin, unfortunately not. I have contacted them but they did not respond. I have used normal Get requested with an setIntervall timer every 20 seconds (which should not expand the rate limit)

Comment: ok, thanks for your reply. you might want to consider using other services, such as blockchain.info :)

Answer (score 1):

You probably reached the limit. Consider adding your BlockCypher token at the end of the websocket URL. This was somehow forgotten in the documentation.